# javascript regex for extracting filename from Content-Disposition header

Tags: javascript, regex

Content-disposition header contains filename which can be easily extracted, but sometimes it contains double quotes, sometimes no quotes and there are probably some other variants too. Can someone write a regex which works in all the cases.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=content.txt
```

Here are some of the possible target strings:

```
attachment; filename=content.txt
attachment; filename*=UTF-8''filename.txt
attachment; filename="EURO rates"; filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates
attachment; filename="omáèka.jpg"
and some other combinations might also be there
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could try something in this spirit:

```
filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)

filename      # match filename, followed by
[^;=\n]*      # anything but a ;, a = or a newline
=
(             # first capturing group
    (['"])    # either single or double quote, put it in capturing group 2
    .*?       # anything up until the first...
    \2        # matching quote (single if we found single, double if we find double)
|             # OR
    [^;\n]*   # anything but a ; or a newline
)
```

Your filename is in the first capturing group: http://regex101.com/r/hJ7tS6

Comment: The matched string should not contain double quotes and "utf-8"

Comment: @adnankamili: The easiest solution is probably to perform this check after, separately from the regex.

Comment: /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/.exec(contentDisposition)[1]

Comment: filename[^;=\n]*=(?:(\\?['"])(.*?)\1|(?:[^\s]+'.*?')?([^;\n]*))

Answer (score 19):

Slightly modified to match my use case (strips all quotes and UTF tags)

`filename\*?=['"]?(?:UTF-\d['"]*)?([^;\r\n"']*)['"]?;?`

https://regex101.com/r/UhCzyI/3

Comment: fails if filename contains '

Answer (score 10):

```
/filename[^;=\n]*=(?:(\\?['"])(.*?)\1|(?:[^\s]+'.*?')?([^;\n]*))/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/hJ7tS6/51

**Edit**: You can also use this parser:
https://github.com/Rob--W/open-in-browser/blob/master/extension/content-disposition.js

Answer (score 5):

```
filename[^;\n]*=(UTF-\d['"]*)?((['"]).*?[.]$\2|[^;\n]*)?
```

I have upgraded [Robin’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23054920/4397397) to do two more things:

1. Capture filename even if it has escaped double quotes.
   [image]
2. Capture UTF-8'' part as a separate group.
   [image]

This is an ECMAScript solution.

https://regex101.com/r/7Csdp4/3/

Comment: I have adapted your regex to allow whitespaces after the = and before the name:

`filename[^;\n]*=\s*(UTF-\d['"]*)?((['"]).*?[.]$\2|[^;\n]*)?`

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** the following answer only works with **PCRE** (e.g. Python / PHP), if you have to use javascript, use Robin's answer.

---

This modified version of Robin's regex strips the quotes:

```
filename[^;\n=]*=(['\"])*(.*)(?(1)\1|)

filename        # match filename, followed by
[^;=\n]*        # anything but a ;, a = or a newline
=
(['"])*         # either single or double quote, put it in capturing group 1
(?:utf-8\'\')?  # removes the utf-8 part from the match
(.*)            # second capturing group, will contain the filename
(?(1)\1|)       # if clause: if first capturing group is not empty,
                # match it again (the quotes), else match nothing
```

https://regex101.com/r/hJ7tS6/28

The filename is in the second capturing group.

Comment: This requires a PCRE flavour of regex—OP asked for JS.

Comment: @miqid yep, sorry about that I edited my answer. I was using python though, so I think my version can be seen as a general solution for the problem for those of us not using javascript.

Comment: res = re.search(r"filename[^;\n=]*=(['\"])*(.*)(?(1)\1|)", string)
res.group(2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my regular expression. It works on Javascript.

```
filename\*?=((['"])[\s\S]*?\2|[^;\n]*)
```

I used this in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I made a regex that finds these names using a group `filename`

```js
/(?<=filename(?:=|\*=(?:[\w\-]+'')))["']?(?<filename>[^"';\n]+)["']?/g
```

```js
const regex = /(?<=filename(?:=|\*=(?:[\w\-]+'')))["']?(?<filename>[^"';\n]+)["']?/g

const filenames = `
attachment; filename=content.txt
attachment; filename*=UTF-8''filename.txt
attachment; filename="EURO rates"; filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates
attachment; filename="omáèka.jpg"
`

function logMatches(){
  const array = new Array

  filenames.split("\n").forEach(line => {
    if(!line.trim()) return

    const matches = line.matchAll(regex)
    const groups = Array.from(matches).map(match => match?.groups?.filename)

    array.push(groups.length === 1 ? groups[0] : groups)
  })

  console.log(array)
}

logMatches()
```