# Akka Http - how to read Content-Disposition from HttpResponse headers?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm using Akka Http to download a file and I'm having trouble extracting the filename from response headers. My response headers look like this:

```
Server: custom_server
Date: Sat, 8 Jul 2017 01:30:39 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
content-disposition: attachment;filename*=UTF-8''my_custom_name.pdf
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
```

When i'm trying to check if the content-disposition header exists I'm always receiving false:

```
val hasDispositionHeader = response.headers.exists {
  case headers.`Content-Disposition`(contentDisposition, params) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Tried to use the java api too with no success:

```
val fileName = response.header[ContentDisposition].get.value
```

I have noticed that the **content-disposition** header key is lowercase (it's a remote server I have no control over) - any idea on how to deal with this?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`lowercaseName`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpHeader.html#lowercaseName():String):

```
val contentDispositionValue =
  response.headers
          .find(_.lowercaseName == "content-disposition")
          .map(_.value)
```

The above returns an `Option[String]` that contains the entire header value.

To get the file name (`my_custom_name.pdf`) from the header value, you have to extract it yourself. If you want to avoid using a regex, as you mentioned in a comment, then you can [`split`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#split(separators:Array[Char]):Array[String]) the `String` on the `''` delimiter:

```
val fileName =
  response.headers
          .find(_.lowercaseName == "content-disposition")
          .map(_.value)
          .map(_.split("''"))
          .collect { case Array(first, second) => second }
```

The above returns an `Option[String]` that contains only the file name. Obviously this will work only for the specific header value format in your example (i.e., the file name is the last part of the header value and is immediately preceded by a `''`, and the `''` appears only once in the header value). For other header value formats you'll have to adapt the approach as needed.

Comment: Thanks a mill. To identify the field is straightforward indeed as you guys pointed - however the value retrieved in this case is the full string:
`attachment;filename*=UTF-8''my_custom_name.pdf`

Was wondering if there was a way to extract **my_custom_name.pdf**  from that string without reverting to regex matching.

Comment: Thanks again - that's how I ended up eventually. With another split on ";" for multiple filenames it covers all cases raised by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054475/javascript-regex-for-extracting-filename-from-content-disposition-header/23054920)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11.1/scala/http/common/http-model.html#HttpResponse, I see `response.headers` is a `Seq`, so:

```
response.headers.find(_name.toLowerCase == "content-disposition")
```